# ADD Event for MBCalendar Kit in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, mbcalendarkit

In my app, i am using the **MBCalendar Kit**

I got the source code from [MBCalendar from CocoaControl](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mbcalendarkit).

But how can I add a new event for displaying in the tableview?

Answer (score 2):

```
 -(void)addEvents:(NSArray *)eventsArray forDate:(NSDate*)date
{
NSMutableArray *myeventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *eventsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (int i =0; i< eventsArray.count ;i++)
{

    // Create events
    eventsDict = eventsArray[i];
    CKCalendarEvent* aCKCalendarEvent = [[CKCalendarEvent alloc] init];
    aCKCalendarEvent.title = [eventsDict  objectForKey:@"email"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.date = date; //[eventsArray  objectForKey:@"phone"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.address = [eventsDict  objectForKey:@"addrLine1"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.image = [eventsDict objectForKey:@"pPic"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.name = [eventsDict objectForKey:@"fname"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.appDate = [eventsDict objectForKey:@"apntDt"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.notes = [eventsDict objectForKey:@"notes"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.phone = [eventsDict objectForKey:@"phone"];
    [myeventsArray addObject: aCKCalendarEvent];
}

     [_data setObject:myeventsArray forKey:date];
     NSLog(@"data %@",_data);


}
```

You can add event like this

Comment: You can call it from your response. You have to pass the required parameters.
CKCalendarEvent this class is there to add data.